# Как тег main растянуть до футера?

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Как тег main растянуть до футера?
Какие css свойства нужно прописать, чтобы main растянулся до футера и тем самым убрать черный фон?

[Сюда](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/?s=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: Задайте тегу <main> и вложенному в него тегу <aside> минимальную фиксированную высоту, при которой будут помещаться весь контент - это будет height:1220px для <aside> и height:980 для <main>, так как ещё 240px забирает псевдоэлемент :after. Либо height:1220px для обоих, но тогда нужно убрать псевдоэлемент :after.

Вариант 2: Задайте тегу <main> и тегу <div class="wrapper"> высоту 100% - height:100%.

Comment: @Евгений_21, только что попробовал второй вариант - черная область стала больше. Может, надо задать min-height?

сейчас попробую первый вариант

Answer (score 0):

Закрыть `<main>` перед футером, не?

```
</main>
<div id = "footer"></div>
```

Comment: @Виталий RS у меня тег main закрыт, смотрите внимательно